# How to test Facebook mobile app install ads “Last Mobile Install Reported” field?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, ads

I've integreated Facebook SDK, and put the code [FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID]; in, and it worked all right with return value true.

I'm testing it using ad hoc distribution, for some reason the field Last Mobile Install Reported is not showing up. And the Facebook app summary page I got seems to be different to other people.

[image: This is my summary page]

[image: This is what others got]

My question is:

1. Do I need to release the app to Apple store first, then download it via Facebook Ad in order for 'Last Mobile Install Reported' to show up?
2. My guess is that since I installed the app as Ad Hoc to my device, not via Facebook, so that 'Last Mobile Install Reported' didn't work. It is fair enough if that is the case, as I expect Facebook to charge me only when people download and install the app via Facebook Ads. But I'm not sure if my guess is all right or not. Can anyone clarify how facebook mobile app install ads works?
   I've read through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/ already btw.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user132490,did you find any solution for this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 11):

I know I'm a little late to answer this but maybe this will help someone else.  I just ran my first ad campaign on fb for my app and tracked installs.

First, the way you test if your app has the fb framework installed correctly and reporting installs is:

Look for the "fb_mobile_activate_app" event to show up in fb in the App Dashboard -> Insights -> App Events -> Overview.  It should show up within a minute of the app opening.

1. Your app does not have to be released.  I was getting install data from the simulator.
2. FB tracks all opens and if that same user clicked on one of your ads within the last 28 days it counts it as an install.

Comment: Going into insights was what I needed, just to make sure my events reach Facebook. Thank you! this was so annoying!!

Comment: Insights is now called "Analytics" btw.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your app do not have to be Released to see that feature. We have seen stats even for our development status app.
2. Last Mobile Install Reported works for non Facebook Ads related installs as well. They basically take in any installs .

It seems like you already have a Mobile Install Reported value in place. I don't think it would report a duplicated device if you set up the Info.plist correctly as instructed in the article below. Under "Advanced steps for mobile measurement", go to step 2.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/

Answer (score 0):

There is a "trick" to seeing your installs.

Yes, you can test "App Installs" on the Simulator or on your device...BUT...you might not see them on the Facebook Dashboard.

Instead, first go to the INSIGHTS tab reached from the left menu on the App Dashboard.
You may see App Installs here - but you might not.

Second, if you don't see any live data for App Installs, look at the section called "APP LAUNCHES."  That can be used as a surrogate indicator that your app is working.

Third, if you don't see live data for "App Launches" - look at the date range. Change the date range to extend to TOMORROW's date.  Give Facebook 1-2 minutes to update with your data. At that point, now you can see that live App Launches are occurring - and thus will know that your connection to FB is working.